# Sonaqube throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be empty

Tags: sonarqube

I integrated SonarQube to my android project but can not execute the command to generate report. 
Here is how I did it:

Environment:

- Android Studio 4.0 Beta 3.
- SonarQube 8.2, community edition.

Project's gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } //Crashlytics
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-beta03'
        ...
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.8"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my app id here>"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 1
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            testCoverageEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [backup: "false"]
            manifestPlaceholders = [backup : "false"]
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [backup: "true"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    flavorDimensions "data"
    productFlavors {
        development {
            dimension "data"
        }

        staging {
            dimension "data"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "data"
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    /*Android Support Libraries*/ 
    ...

    /*Firebase Libraries */
    ...
    /*Other 3rd party libs*/
    ...

    kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    kapt "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    annotationProcessor "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "<ProjectName>"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "<project_key>"
        property "sonar.tests", ["src/test/java"]
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
                '*.json,' +
                '**/*test*/**,' +
                '**/.gradle/**,' +
                '**/R.class'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I download and unzip SonarQube 8.2, then run this command to start it successfully, :

`~/Documents/sonarqube/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console`

then I'm able to login to `http:localhost:9000` and setup new project with specified project key and get back the token.

I copied the command generated by Sonar and ran in terminal but it always throws exception.

Command:

```
./gradlew sonarqube \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=gluu_android \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=e694bbca8f20ad86fd02b5620521f92073d411ef
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Build Event Notification" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be empty
        at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.util.Args.containsNoBlanks(Args.java:84)
        at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:80)
        at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:99)
        at com.crashlytics.api.net.proxy.ProxySettings.getConfig(ProxySettings.java:39)
        at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi.notifyBuildEvent(RestfulWebApi.java:1439)
        at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi.access$100(RestfulWebApi.java:74)
        at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi$10.run(RestfulWebApi.java:1371)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Sonar background thread's exception:

````
Error Details
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures: 1 errors among 1 requests
    at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
    at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.server.measure.index.ProjectMeasuresIndexer.doIndex(ProjectMeasuresIndexer.java:157)
    at org.sonar.server.measure.index.ProjectMeasuresIndexer.indexOnAnalysis(ProjectMeasuresIndexer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.step.IndexAnalysisStep.execute(IndexAnalysisStep.java:45)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeStep(ComputationStepExecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:72)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:209)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.run(CeWorkerImpl.java:191)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:158)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$TrackRunningState.get(CeWorkerImpl.java:133)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:85)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem after these steps:

- install PostgreSQL  from `https://www.postgresql.org/`
- Clean up my mac to get more than 50GB of freespace